# Model binding to Lists throws "Collection is read-only" exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a class like this:

```
public class SomeModel
{
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }

    public SomeModel()
    {
        this.Items = new List<Item>();
    }

}
```

Where there can be a variable amount of `Item`s upon form post, zero to many. I'm using javascript to dynamically append hidden input fields on submit:

```
$("#container").children(".item").each(function (i) {
    form.append('<input type="hidden" name="Items[' + i + '].Id" value="' + $(this).val() + '" />');
});
```

However, after submitting, I get this error:

```
System.NotSupportedException: Collection is read-only.
```

The rendered syntax is basically the same as one I would get using `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Items[i].Id)` with `model.Items` being an array instead of a list, and that works fine. What is going wrong here?

Action Method signature:

```
public ActionResult Post(SomeModel m)
{
```

Comment: Can you show the Action method signature?

Comment: which line are you getting the error ?

Comment: @Shyju Some time after the `SomeModel()` constructor is excited out of (right before it gets to `Post`).

Comment: show your action method as well

Comment: @Shyju The `[HttpGet]` or `[HttpPost]` one? It never reaches the action method before it errors out anyway.

Comment: you need to provide more details for a second person to understand your situation and give an answer. The view and action methods would be good.

Answer (score 21):

Your Array was probably working on Insert (Where a new object is created).

The issue happens when you try to update your model.

For me, replacing `string[]` to `List<string>` solved the problem.

```
//instead of....
public string[] TagsArray { get; set; }

//I now have
public List<string> TagsArray { get; set; }
```

Comment: is there some documentation backing the reason behind this?

Answer (score 2):

MVC Model Binder should work with arrays, so replacing with a List is a workaround, but not the right solution.

I had the same problem, but it happens to me only sometimes. So I did not understand why this issue takes place. Then I discovered something that I think is worhty to share: **the problem was in the javascript code**.

Here my scenario:

I have a model where I use one array

```
public class SomeModel
{
    public Item[] Items { get; set; }

    public SomeModel()
    {
        this.Items = new Item[3] {0, 0, 0};
    }
}
```

I found the solution just changing the javascript that I use to call the web method!

-> case A - **It throws the exception "Collection is read only"**

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: true,
        url: myUrl,
        data: JSON.stringify(myData),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "html"
    })
```

-> case B - **It works without any exception!**

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: true,
        url: myUrl,
        data: myData,
        dataType: "html"
    })
```

Actually MVC model binding should works with array, so replacing with a List was not the answer I was looking for.

Good coding.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why the array worked before, but apparently, that was what was causing the problem--not the Lists. When I changed that array to a List, I no longer got the error. Should've mentioned that I still had the array in my model, sorry.

Answer (score -2):

If a list is made with `IList<string> list = new List<string>(stringArray);` where `stringArray` is type `string[]` then it cannot be appended to because it is really an array with limited space.  If you make it with `IList<string> list = new List<string>();` and then use a `foreach` to transfer each element of the array into the list then it will be capable of expanding.